# What are the pros and cons of Cloud based Backend for Mobile Applications eg. Parse

Tags: android, push-notification, parse-platform, backend, mobile-application

Thanks to all for their earlier support. Now these days i am looking for a Framework Which can provide backend support for Android Applications. I found one of them is Parse [Here](https://www.parse.com/docs/index) . Although i didn't initiate any implementation based on the same but it seems very promising after once visit their portal, dashboard and documentation. Can anybody describe pros and cons of using such Framework. If anybody have any experience to work upon Parse Framework please share your feedback should i go ahead in the reference. Is it free to start like developing demo Apps. Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The basic plan, which is all you need to get started, is free.

The most important reason, in my opinion, to use a service like Parse is that you can focus on your app, and what's special about it, and let someone else make sure your backend just works. A service like that will scale to whatever number of users your app gets (providing you design it correctly). The API is also quite similar between the platforms they support (like Android, iOS etc) so that the backend does not create obstacles in the event you need to port your app to other platforms.

You also have the advantage that the API is so similar to the programming you're already doing with your app so it fits very well with your existing code.

Just make sure you design your backend with a NoSQL mindset and don't fall in the trap of trying to implement a SQL-ish model that will not scale. Going through the Anypic tutorial on their site is a good primer if you are not used to designing for NoSQL databases.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for this reply, It's free to start practice when they will ask to pay for all support and services.

Comment: Was this meant as a question? You can see the plan differences here: https://parse.com/plans  If you need "dedicated support", you need to pay (of course, I must say). But you will often get the answers you need on the parse.com forums, or here on SO. There is no need to pay anything until you go live in production with your app. And maybe not even then. But paying for a production service should be ok :-)